# Laravel 5.8: Laravel Passport API Authentication Issue Outside PHP artisan serve

Tags: angular, laravel-5, laravel-passport, unauthorized

I am encountering an authentication problem with my Laravel API when attempting to run it without using PHP artisan serve. I have implemented Passport for authentication.

The authentication process works seamlessly when using php artisan serve and accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login in tools like Insomnia. However, I am facing issues when trying to run the Laravel backend independently and connecting it to an Angular frontend.

Despite exploring various solutions suggested online, including updating the .htaccess files in both the root and public folders, the API consistently returns an "unauthenticated" error.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or can provide insights into how to make Laravel Passport authentication work outside of php artisan serve, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

- Updated the .htaccess files in both the root and public folders as recommended in online resources.
- Checked the Laravel Passport configuration for any misconfigurations.
- Verified that the Laravel backend is accessible outside of php artisan serve.
- Ensured that the Angular frontend is making requests to the correct API endpoints.
- Checked for any relevant error messages in the Laravel logs.

Expectation:

I expected the Laravel Passport authentication to work seamlessly when the backend is accessed independently (without using php artisan serve) from my Angular frontend. However, despite these efforts, the API consistently returns an "unauthenticated" error.